# Getting mySql data from url in swift 3 - again

Tags: swift

I have asked this seemingly very simple and straight forward question a few times now, never got a solution.

I have a url to obtain mySql data

```
// 1. get url
let url = URL(string:"http://www.mobwebplanet.com/phpWebService/sample.php")

// 2. Fetch data from url
let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
//playground Output is: 102 bytes. So obviously xcode gets the response data from the URL.
```

Then I move on to extracting the data:

```
//3. Create a dictionary from data:
let urlDict  = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])

// playground Output is: [["Latitude": "37.331741", "Address": "1 Infinite Loop Cupertino, CA", "Name": "Apple", "Longitude": "-122"]]
print(urlDict!)

// playground Output is: "(\n        {\n        Address = "1 Infinite Loop Cupertino, CA";\n        Latitude = "37.331741";\n        Longitude = "-122";\n        Name = Apple;\n    }\n)\n"
```

My understanding is `urlDict` is of a `Any` type. Am I correct?

My biggest question is how can I (cast or convet) `urlDict` so that I can access the value using key=>value? Like this:

```
 urlDict!["Address"] Outputs "1 Infinite Loop Cupertino, CA"
 urlDict!["Latitude"] Outputs "37.331741"...
```

I am a newbie to Swift so I am doing this as an exercise, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON response returns an Array of Dictionary objects. So you just need to cast correctly.

```
let urlString = "http://www.mobwebplanet.com/phpWebService/sample.php"
let url = URL(string: urlString)!

let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)

if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [[String:Any]] {
    for location in json! {
        print(location["Longitude"])
        print(location["Latitude"])
        print(location["Address"])
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Optional(-122)
Optional(37.331741)
Optional(1 Infinite Loop Cupertino, CA)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Finally there is an answer that makes sense to my dumb mind! :)